# Kwargs in Django

Tags: python, django

What are Kwarg!!??

I have been going through a tutorial in django, trying to learn the language, and I stumbled on this.

I would really appreciate if some can post / point to a simple example that would help grasp why and how this is used.

Comment: Try the Python tutorial instead. [Keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).

Comment: The language is not "Django". The language is Python.

Comment: See the similar question [#3394835](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs) (*args and **kwargs)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star) and \* (star) do for Python parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)

Answer (score 10):

Based on [Keyword arguments' documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) pointed out by *@Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams*

> **kwargs allows you to **handle named arguments that you have not
>   defined in advance**.
>
> In a function call, keyword arguments **must follow positional
>   arguments**.
>
> All the keyword arguments passed **must match one of the
>   arguments accepted by the function** (e.g. actor is not a valid
>   argument for the parrot function), and **their order is not
>   important**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this awesome explanation [from digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3).

In summary, **kwargs is dict that holds parameters and can be used by first passing it through a view func e.g

`def fun(req, **kwargs)`

and then get values inside the function like this

`kwargs.get('key_name')`.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this article](https://djangocentral.com/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/)

```
def print_kwargs(**kwargs):
    for key in kwargs:
        print("The key {} holds {} value".format(key, kwargs[key]))


print_kwargs(a=1, b=2, c="Some Text")
```

**Output:**

```
The key a holds 1 value
The key b holds 2 value
The key c holds Some Text value
```