# Django Views.py: kwargs and serializer w/o explicit reference in class definition

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm following along with a Django Rest Framework tutorial ([source code here](https://github.com/ShubhamSarda/IMDB-Clone-DRF/blob/main/watchlist_app/api/views.py)) and I have a few questions about the below code snippet:

```py
class ReviewCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    throttle_classes = [ReviewCreateThrottle]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Review.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        watchlist = WatchList.objects.get(pk=pk)

        review_user = self.request.user
        review_queryset = Review.objects.filter(watchlist=watchlist, review_user=review_user)

        if review_queryset.exists():
            raise ValidationError("You have already reviewed this movie!")

        if watchlist.number_rating == 0:
            watchlist.avg_rating = serializer.validated_data['rating']
        else:
            watchlist.avg_rating = (watchlist.avg_rating + serializer.validated_data['rating'])/2

        watchlist.number_rating = watchlist.number_rating + 1
        watchlist.save()

        serializer.save(watchlist=watchlist, review_user=review_user)
```

1. In the class definition, the variable `serializer_class` is declared; however in the `perform_create` method, `serializer` is an argument. Given the differences in naming, how are these two related?
2. In the method `perform_create`, `self.kwargs` is referenced. However, I don't see a kwargs argument passed to any `__init__` method or else attached to the class object. How/where is kwargs passed to the class?

In both cases, I can only assume that the inherited class (`generics.CreateAPIView`) has an `__init__` method that assigns a `serializer_class` variable to `serializer`. How it "listens" for a child class definition of `serializer_class`, I have no idea. And as for kwargs, I'm at a loss for how this is passed to the child class w/o explicitly calling defining it in its arguments.

Edit, this question [Kwargs in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255913/kwargs-in-django) does not answer my question-- it just explains what keyword arguments are. I'm not confused about their name, I'm confused by their invisible yet implicit reference in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your first point, we have to note two things:

- First, the method `perform_create` is used in the `create` method associated to `CreateModelMixin` (see https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/71e6c30034a1dd35a39ca74f86c371713e762c79/rest_framework/mixins.py#L16). The class `CreateAPIView` inherits from this mixin and also from `GenericAPIView`(See https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/b1004a47334a0dd1929e6d50b8f7ff6badc959f4/rest_framework/generics.py#L184). As you can see, the `create` method mentioned above uses the class `perform_create` method and needs a serializer there. Defining `perform_create` without that argument would lead to an error when creating objects with this method.
- Another thing to note is that the serializer used comes from the `get_serializer` method. Checking the source code for `GenericAPIView` (https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/b1004a47334a0dd1929e6d50b8f7ff6badc959f4/rest_framework/generics.py#L103) we can see that this method calls `get_serializer_class` which retrieves the serializer defined by `serializer_class`.

In conclusion, if you don't modify anything else, the `serializer` that will be passed as a parameter will be an instance of you serializer class defined in `serializer_class`.

Getting to your second point, if you try to search the parent class of `GenericAPIView` and follow on searching the base class from which these classes inherit, you will end up finding that the base class is `View` from `django.views.generic`. There you will find in the `setup` method (https://github.com/django/django/blob/27aa7035f57f0db30b6632e4274e18b430906799/django/views/generic/base.py#L124) where the `kwargs` attribute is initialized. Also you can see in this method's code documentation the following statement:

```
"""Initialize attributes shared by all view methods."""
```

Thus in any view we create (if it has `View` as its base class) we will always be able to manipulate `self.request`, `self.args` and `self.kwargs`. I hope I explained myself clearly!